# RunAs admin in weblogic to access mbean

Tags: java, weblogic-10.x

Need some help in mbean access in weblogic. I have a user who is not Administrator and I need to access one mbean attribute which requires access to admin role. Can someone please help me with the approach? 
My java code works fine if I use the admin user (weblogic), but fails and throws following  exception for other non-admin users.

```
Access denied. Required roles: Admin, Operator, Monitor, executing subject: principals=[xxx] java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied. Required roles: Admin, Operator, Monitor, executing subject: principals=[xxx]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CredentialAccessFramework and making an entry in system-jazn.

Update system policies so that a jar can access the mbean using admin credential stored in credential access framework.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/core.1111/e10043/devcsf.htm#JISEC3671